# Got following error in running server "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java/lang/Object.toString()Ljava/lang/String;"

Tags: java, spring, weblogic, cxf

Folks,

We had weird incidence in running server. Below mentioned exceptions (snapshot) were observed continuously. Restarting the server resolved the issue and issue was not observed any more. So I am not sure why a running server would run into NoSuchMethodError which was observed only once in my application in last 1 year. I tried looking for some info around, but couldn't find any relevant information behind cause. So posting this to get some pointers.

Thank you,
Pathik

1)--------------------------

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com/ibm/wsdl/extensions/soap/SOAPHeaderImpl.getPart()Ljava/lang/String;
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29518.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ExtensionInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtensionInvocationHandler.java:42)
    at $Proxy114.getPart(Unknown Source)
```

2)---------------------------

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myBean5' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/v2_0/myApplicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'myBean1' while setting bean property 'myProperty3' with key [3]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myBean1' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/myApplicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'myBean2' while setting bean property 'myProperty4' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myBean2' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/myApplicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java/lang/Object.toString()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:880)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork.spring.SpringObjectFactory.buildBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:134)
```

3)--------------------------------

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myBean2' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/myApplicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java/lang/Object.toString()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:480)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:283)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java/lang/Object.toString()Ljava/lang/String;
```

Comment: For sure, Version conflict of some jar. see any differnent versions of jars are there in lib folder.

Comment: @SURESH if it was version conflict, how would restarting the server solve the issue ?

Comment: Conflicting jar could be one of the suspect, we tried to look for different version of mentioned class, but so far jars look good. Another confusion is cause  <br/>  **Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java/lang/Object.toString()Ljava/lang/String;** - I am wondering how Object.toString() which returns String is not there..!!